# Django Model inheritance error "field ... clashes with the field"

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-one

I'm having a problem when using multi-table inheritance in Django and I didn't find something that solved it.

I have these two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12, default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, default="")
    birthday = models.DateField()

class Parent(Person):
    work = models.CharField(max_length=70, default="")
    spouce_field = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=DO_NOTHING, related_name="spouce_field")
```

And I get this error when running `python3 manage.py makemigrations`:

```
ERRORS:

family.Parent.spouce_field: (models.E006) The field 'spouce_field' clashes with the field 'spouce_field' from model 'person.person'.
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'd probably want `symmetric=True` on the OneToOneField. Also, why is that one named `..._field` when none of the other fields are? :)

Comment: I think symmetric is only used in many to many, isn't it? When putting it on the OneToOneField I get an error saying `an unexpected keyword argument`.
The ..._field is just an attempt of mine to change the actual name of the field, I thought it might fix the problem, it clearly did not :)

Comment: Ah, my bad on the `symmetric`. Either way, then you'll need `spouse = models.OneToOneField("Person", related_name="reverse_spouse")` or similar, but it still easily gets pretty weird data-model-wise since you could conceivably have a chain of spouses :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe [mrcai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6691866/mrcai) have answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38832733/14550345):

Mark your class `Person` as an abstract class to avoid field clashing.

> You can specify Profile is an abstract class. This will stop the check
> from being confused with your parent fields.
>
> ```
> class Meta:
>    abstract = True
> ```